# Correlation audio opencv

Tags: opencv, audio, correlation

I guess use of opencv correlation, I need to know if a piece of an audio file is inside another audio file, can anyone tell me how I could proceed?
Or another solution?

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

Correlation might be the right tool for the job if the problem you are trying to solve is checking for the occurrence of an exact section of one file in another. However, if the following are true you will need another solution:

- You intend searching a corpus (e.g. a database of files) for occurrences [Scales badly]
- The audio has been processed (e.g. stretched, compressed) [correlation not particularly robust]

The usual way of solving this problem is with *Feature Extraction* and *feature matching* algorithms.  Whilst OpenCV provides examples of both of these types of algorithms for image processing, it is probably not the weapon of choice for audio.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply and for the tip, but for my job I was asked to use opencv for this, I already have the data in a struct wav, now I need to manipulate it using opencv, thus making the correlation.